# Unable to remove event listener via content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have HTML page with a `form` tag that has a `submit` event listener attached to it via Javascript file.

I want to remove this listener from content script in Chrome extension but it seems that it doesn't do anything. If I run the same code from the Chrome console, it is removed as expected.

```
$(function() {
  $('#someform').off('submit');
});
```

Why?

Comment: How are you registering the event listener?  And is this reproducible in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Yes, please do as @tpdietz suggests and put the code for your "...event listener attached to it via Javascript file" within your question so we may review that.  It may be related to the way the event listener is bound.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#someform").off("submit"); })
```

You said that it is working on chrome console. So maybe this is the solution. If I misunderstood the question, I am sorry.

Comment: This appears to be the same as the code in the OP's question, perhaps you missed something? (different syntax but same thing)